# Running F# tests on F# Interactive

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, f#, f#-interactive

I tend to write some quick prototypes on algorithms on F# script files (that I don't really intend to later on migrate into `.fs` files, although it could well be a possibility) and I'd like to easily test them. What's the quickest way to do some *real* NUnit/FsUnit tests in F# while running them through F# Interactive?

Well, running them in Visual Studio's Test Runner would be amazing as long as it didn't me bring any extra trouble, I want the KISSest solution possible!

Comment: you can add any assembly with `#r ...` - just write you a template `.fsx` with your favorite test-framework/runner referenced and enjoy ...

Comment: What do you mean *real* unit tests through F# Interactive? You can send any function to FSI, including unit test functions. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

If you host your script file in an F# Tutorial project then you can run your unit tests defined in the script with Visual Studio's built-in test runner. If you're using NUnit be sure to install the [NUnit Test Adapter extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d).

```
#r "nunit.framework.dll"

open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let ``2 + 2 should equal 4`` () =
  Assert.AreEqual(4, 2 + 2)
```

Alternatively to run a single test just execute the body of your test function or invoke your function:

```
``2 + 2 should equal 4`` ()
```

Finally I have an NUnit test runner script that you can use to run batches of tests in F# interactive without needing to copy out the function names, see [Running TAP](http://trelford.com/blog/post/TAP.aspx).

Comment: "If you host your script file in an F# Tutorial project then you can run your unit tests defined in the script with Visual Studio's built-in test runner". I've installed the said plugin but when I run your code on FsI I don't see VS test-runner running the tests (I do see FsI output, though).

Comment: To run unit tests with the built-in Visual Studio test runner you need to select the Test menu at the top and click on Run -> All Tests. To see the results go to the Test menu again and click on Windows -> Test Explorer. Alternatively you can use a third-party runner like Test Driven .Net.